# How execute spring repository method in for comprehension with implicit

Tags: scala, spring-data-jpa, scala-cats, cats-effect

I want to save data from telegram api in for comprehension type with implicit, but have an error

```
Error:(61, 9) type mismatch;
 found   : cats.effect.IO[Unit]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[?]
      _ <- IO(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get)))
```

The code in TelegramBot example, which use info.mukel.telegrambot4s 3.0.9 library.

```
  onCommand("/hello") { implicit msg =>
    for {
      _   <- reply(s"Hello ${msg.from.get.firstName}")
      _ <- IO(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get)))
    } yield ()
  }
```

I tried to delete reply and add, this code compiled, but saving (inside IO) didn`t execute

```
  onCommand("/hello") { implicit msg =>
    for {
      res <- IO(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get)))
    } yield res
  }
```

Is it possible to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
onCommand("/hello") { implicit msg =>
  for {
    _ <- IO.fromFuture(IO.pure(reply(s"Hello ${msg.from.get.firstName}")))
    _ <- IO(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, isBot = true, msg.from.get.username.get)))
  } yield ()
}
```

Comment: But the _ <- IO(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get))) is not executed.

Comment: Tried IO.apply(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get)))

Comment: IO.pure(userRepository.save(User(msg.from.get.id, msg.from.get.username.get)))